# Android TranslateAnimation with Button View problem

Tags: android, animation, sdk

I'm trying to *have fun* with android animations. This is the crime scene:
I've a relative layout with the following components:

1. On the background we placed a ListView 200dip wide.
2. Hover the ListView we added: one Button 40dip wide, 2nd ListView 80dip wide and a 3rd ListView 80dip wide.

   As first thing I would like to show the ListView behind the other components. Once the user selects an item I want to show the other components hover the first listView coming from right with a TranslateAnimation.

I hope you can understand my poor english.

Have fun and have a good week!

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you open the ApiDemos demo project provided with the Android SDK.  Look at the activities:

animation1
animation2
animation3

There are also plenty of tutorials by googling "android translate animation example," or something else of that nature.